# Wordpress Rest API with advanced custom fields Google map field returns weird string

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, google-maps

I want to use a Wordpress backend with advanced custom fields and the json Wordpress API to serve data to a mobile app.

For this project the client needs to select a location in the maps custom field. The API should return a json array with some other data and the data from the Google maps field.

The object the API returns is formatted as follows:

```
{
"0": [
    {
      "title": "Test 1",
      "evenement_afbeelding": "38",
      "kunstenaars": "Name One",
      "openingstijden": "9:00 - 18:30",
      "evenementbeschrijving": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ac pharetra tortor.",
      "evenement_lokatie": "a:3:{s:7:\"address\";s:40:\"Jansweg 50, 2011 KN Haarlem, Netherlands\";s:3:\"lat\";s:17:\"52.38513460768028\";s:3:\"lng\";s:17:\"4.638633728027344\";}",
      "biografie": "<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong>\r\n\r\nConsectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ac pharetra tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos."
    }
],
    "status": "ok"
}
```

The weird thing is that the value on key "evenement_lokatie" (the Google maps field) returns a string that I cannot convert to an array. The value on the "evenement_lokatie" key should contain another array like this:

```
{
"0": [
    {
      "title": "Test 1",
      "evenement_afbeelding": "38",
      "kunstenaars": "Name One",
      "openingstijden": "9:00 - 18:30",
      "evenementbeschrijving": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ac pharetra tortor.",
      "evenement_lokatie": [
        {
          "Stad": "Haarlem",
          "lang": "32143241",
          "lat": "721321"
        }
  ],
      "biografie": "<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong>\r\n\r\nConsectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ac pharetra tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos."
    }
],
    "status": "ok"
}
```

This is the PHP code that should format the data in wordpress:

```
<?php


class json_api_events_controller{

    public function hello_world(){
        return array('message'=>'Hello World!');
    }

    public function get_events(){
        $array = array();


        $args = array('post_type'=>'evenementen', 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'order_by'=>'title', 'order'=>'ASC');
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        $counter = 0;

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            $id = get_the_id();
            $custom = get_post_custom($id);

            // add the title
            $array[$id][$counter]['title'] = get_the_title();

            // add all the custom fields
            foreach($custom as $k => $v){

                // if key starts with '_' symbol, don't add to the array
                if(strpos($k, '_') !== 0) {

                    $array[$id][$counter][$k] = array_shift($v);

                }
            }

            $counter++;
        endwhile;


        return $array;
    }

}
```

Also there are weird chracters in the string, like ";s:17:" and ";s:40:".
Can anyone show me how I can convert such a string to an array like I described?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *The value on the "evenement_lokatie" key should contain another array like this:* are you sure? Did you read the docs to see if this is indeed the format JSON output you get? Or is this just the format you *wanted*?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry, I should have been more clear. The second example is actually the format I need, not necceceraly what i expected. In either case I didn't expect the string to be formatted like this, with the ;s:40 characters.

Comment: You can have a look at [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and use it while iterating over your json_decoded array elements (specificaly the `evenement_lokatie` one)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this approach since or is not really future proof. But it seems it is the only way to go. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "weird" value is actually serialized PHP - you can deserialize it serverside using [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) before you [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), and you should be fine.

Wordpress serializes metadata in this way, so that any object can be saved as strings. The trick is to use PHP deserialization to get a valid PHP object before creating the valid JSON object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved it is to query the posts, get the location field and it's data, add two meta fields for lat and lng.

The query:

```
  while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $location = get_field('location');
    $lat = $location['lat'];
    $lng = $location['lng'];
    if (! metadata_exists( 'post', $id, 'lat' ) ) {
      add_post_meta($id, 'lat', $lat, true);
    }
    if (! metadata_exists( 'post', $id, 'lng' ) ) {
      add_post_meta($id, 'lng', $lng, true);
    }
```

And then since I am using javascript, I am reading that data like this:

```
      $.each(data, function(i) {
        var lat = data[i]["details"]["lat"];
        var lng = data[i]["details"]["lng"];
```