# How to unserialize a string in a json?

Tags: php, wordpress

This how I get the json:

```
$response = wp_remote_get(get_home_url()."2/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include=".$userPostsExternal);
var_dump($response);
```

Then I get

```
"details":{  ...

   "location":[  
      "a:3:{s:7:\"address\";s:95:\"Avinguda de la Granvia de l\u2019Hospitalet, 8, 08902 L'Hospitalet de Llobregat, Barcelona, Spagna\";s:3:\"lat\";s:17:\"41.36256133817761\";s:3:\"lng\";s:17:\"2.131976960327165\";}"
```

[This answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34876373/1018804):

> The "weird" value is actually serialized PHP - you can deserialize it
>   serverside using unserialize before you json_encode, and you should be
>   fine.
>
> Wordpress serializes metadata in this way, so that any object can be
>   saved as strings. The trick is to use PHP deserialization to get a
>   valid PHP object before creating the valid JSON object.

I [read the php doc](https://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

And I tried the following but it's wrong, I've never used `unserialize`

```
unserialize($response["details"]["location"])
```

this gives the message

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: ? rather than `var_dump` why not `json_decode($response)` ?

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given @RamRaider

Answer (score 1):

Your location data is also an array, so you are missing the last level to access the actual serialized data...

```
unserialize($response["details"]["location"])
```

needs to be

```
$data = unserialize($response["details"]["location"][0]);
```

You can then

```
print_r($data);
```

to see the new data.

Comment: I get no results

Comment: Try using `echo $response["details"]["location"][0];` to check what the field contains.

Comment: You also need to assign the value (I've updated the answer) to access the data.

Comment: still nothing, Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: I have tried it with the data you posted in your question and have not problems getting the results.  If you use `print_r($response["details"]["location"]);` then this should show you what the array structure is.

Comment: i stil don't get any results